# VBA Runtime Error 424 Object Required

Tags: vba, runtime-error

Here is the FULL code..

```
Private Declare Function RegOpenKey Lib "advapi32.dll" _
   Alias "RegOpenKeyA" (ByVal Hkey As Long, ByVal lpSubKey As String, _
   phkResult As Long) As Long
Declare Function RegQueryValue Lib "advapi32.dll" _
   Alias "RegQueryValueA" (ByVal Hkey As Long, ByVal lpSubKey As String, _
   ByVal lpValue As String, lpcbValue As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function RegCloseKey _
   Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal Hkey As Long) As Long



Public Sub AccessAnObject()
   ' Holds an indeterminate object.
    Dim AObj As InlineShape
   ' Holds the BMP file class.
    Dim BMPClass As String
   ' Holds picture statistical data.
    Dim Output As String
   ' Holds the Registry key reference.
    Dim RegKeyRef As Long
   ' Holds the length of the Registry data.
    Dim RegLength As Long
   ' Get the BMP file class.
   ' Open the Registry key.
   RegOpenKey ROOT_KEYS.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, ".bmp", RegKeyRef
   ' Determine whether the key exists.
   If RegKeyRef = 0 Then
      ' Display an error.
      MsgBox "Couldn't open BMP file Registry setting.", _
         vbOKOnly Or vbExclamation, _
         "Registry Error"
     ' Exit the sub.
     Exit Sub
   End If


   ' Determine whether the required information exists. If
   ' so, get the data length.
   RegQueryValue RegKeyRef, "", BMPClass, RegLength
   ' Fill the string with the required spaces.
   BMPClass = VBA.String(RegLength, " ") ' Retrieve the value.
   RegQueryValue RegKeyRef, "", BMPClass, RegLength
   BMPClass = Left(BMPClass, Len(BMPClass) - 1)
   ' Close the Registry.
   RegCloseKey (RegKeyRef)
   ' Check each inline shape.
   For Each AObj In ThisDocument.InlineShapes
     ' Select the object and show that it is selected.
     AObj.Select
     MsgBox "Object Number " + _
       CStr(AObj.Field.Index) + " is Selected", _
       vbInformation Or vbOKOnly, "Object Select"
     ' If this is a sound object, play it.
     If AObj.OLEFormat.ClassType = "SoundRec" Then
       AObj.OLEFormat.DoVerb wdOLEVerbPrimary
     End If

     ' If this is a picture object, display some
     ' statistics.
     If AObj.OLEFormat.ClassType = BMPClass Then
       ' Get the height and width and then display it.
       Output = "Height: " + CStr(AObj.Height) + _
         vbCrLf + _
         CStr(Application.PointsToInches(AObj.Height)) _
         + " Inches" + vbCrLf + _
         "Width: " + CStr(AObj.Width) + vbCrLf + _
         CStr(Application.PointsToInches(AObj.Width)) _
         + " Inches"
      MsgBox Output, vbInformation Or vbOKOnly, _
        "Picture Statistics"
     End If
    Next
End Sub
```

wish you could run this in your own laptops too an see whats the problem.. Others help me in declaring functions and sub but this time its runtime error 424 exist.. :(

To those who can help me THANK YOU SO MUCH!!

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: Please show us which line causes the error. Also, learning to properly format your code makes it easier for you (and us) to read. Thanks.

Comment: When i click debug  RegOpenKey ROOT_KEYS.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, ".bmp", RegKeyRef is highlighted(color Yellow)